# Which is faster? Multi-threading VS Multi-tasking approach

Tags: multithreading, process, multiprocessing, multiprocess

As we know that Multitasking involves running multiple processes and multithreading, on the other hand, is running multiple threads which share the same memory space of process

So I want to know which approach seems to be better and faster in terms of Computer Systems?

Which can bring a noticeable difference in performance?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is, of course, too broad.

Answer (score 2):

As SergeyA has indicated, this is an awfully broad question. The answer is really going to depend upon the problem being solved.

If the various tasks are large separate with only occasional communication between them, then multiple processes offers the advantage of being able to split the processes across different compute servers.

If the tasks are tightly coupled, then the inter-process communications can eat up a lot of that advantage. At that point, multithreading is most likely more efficient and most likely easier to implement.

Creating multiple processes can be somewhat expensive. Spawning threads is exceedingly easy. That becomes a factor.

Resources required can also be a factor. If you're processing a large dataset and do that across processes, then each process needs to pull the dataset into memory. That takes both time and memory. If you multithread, you can load it once and share the data between your threads.

So it depends. For most problems, multithreading is probably significantly faster than using multiple processes, but as soon as you encounter hardware limitations, that answer goes out the window.